# How did Crusher Creel survive contact with the Obelisk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In season two of *Marvel's Agents of SHIELD* Jiaying states that the metal of which Diviners are constructed is poisonous to anyone who is not Inhuman. If this is the case, and Crusher Creel, as has been stated multiple times in the show, is not Inhuman, how did he survive contact with the Obelisk? Why did it not turn him to stone as it did with Isabel Hartley, Triplett, and others?

Comment: I think it was because he was able to turn his body into non-living matter, no? Didn’t he turn his hand into rubber or something before touching it?

Answer (score 8):

Initially it appears to be his ability to transform into various materials that protects him, but later in season 2:

> He has his powers disrupted by the sonic weapon from season 1 and gets turned to stone completely.

However, in season 3:

> it is revealed that he survives this, and that his power gives him a unique resistance not only to the metal but may also provide the key to a vaccine against terrigenesis (episode 12: The Inside Man). The vaccine idea isn't fully fleshed out though, and I suspect we may see more in a later season.

Answer (score 4):

His special ability allowed him to survive contact with an Obelisk by changing his skin into something else.

When he returns the Obelisk to Bashki, he complains about how the object almost killed him, despite turning his skin into rubber to avoid contact with it:

> That thing really messed me up... I turned to rubber when I touched it, thought that it would protect me but it infected me too.

While it didn't entirely prevent the Obelisk from "attacking" him, transforming his skin into an inert substance must have "insulated" him from the effects of the Obelisk long enough to steal it and take it back to HYDRA.